# cannot read property '0' of undefined vm1732:2

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

[image: This is the screenshot of console of one the site I am working]

I am using google tag manager for managing pixels in the website.
from past 3-4 days i felt that there are problems with data received in GTM.
So in GTM debug mode i am getting `no tags fired` message some times.When i refresh the same page it fires the required tags. So i was inspecting the console i cam across this message. I googled it, but not links came up. I have pasted the screenshot of the error here. If anybody has any clue what is that and if that is the issue my GTM tags are not fired.

Anyhelp at least where to start looking

EDIT---------------
This question I posted as part of my investigation on why my GTM was not firing my tags properly. After googling i came across same issues with other people also. GTM is getting upgraded to new version. So our problem also started on the same our GTM got upgraded to new version.

I found a thread in google support forum with my exact same issue.https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/vNdy8db5MvQ;context-place=forum/tag-manager

Any body has any idea why this is happening. I can provide more information if required

Comment: When you click on "vm1732:2", whats the code on the line it sends you to?

Comment: ah somebody down voted this after 1 year and no reasons mentioned.